Typescript record type confusion
I have the following type:
export type ApiKey = string | Record<string, string>;

const apiOb: ApiKey = ... 

Now, I have a key and want to get a value of that key, such as:
let key:string="somekey"
apiOb[key] // This doesn't work

The error I get is:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type
'string' can't be used to index type 'ApiKey'.


You've said that apiOb might be a string. Since that's a possibility, then trying to access an arbitrary property on it is not allowed, just like the following would not be allowed
const apiObj = "hello";
const key = "somekey";
apiObj[key] // strings don't have a "somekey" property

If there is no possibility that apiOb is a string, then give it a different type:
const apiOb: Record<string, string> = ...

Or if string is a possibility, rule that out before you try to use it as a record:
const key: string = "somekey";
if (typeof apiOb === 'string') {
  // do something
} else {
  // Now we've determined that it must be a record, and can access it as one
  apiOb[key]
}

